# Sending mail failed in php

Tags: php

I am trying to send email using mail function in php:

```
$subject = 'testing';
$email = 'test@gmail.com';
$message = 'test message';          
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: The test site" . "\r\n";

if (mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
  $data['msg']="Message send successfully";
} 
else {
  $data['msg']="Please try again, Message could not be sent!";
}
```

I Encounter following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 501 Syntax error in parameters or arguments

Filename: sendemail.php

Line Number: 40
```

I might guess that error was due to not setting configuration required for sending email in php. What should I need to do or I have to change in php.ini file but it's not accesible. Any solution please?

Comment: are u sending mail thru localhost??

Comment: check `$message ='test message;` it should be enclosed in a quote.

Comment: That must be a copy-paste error in the question. If that were the real problem, he'd be getting a syntax error, not an error from the `mail()` function.

Comment: @Barmar If it was copied and pasted and it's wrong here, it's wrong wherever it came from :)

Comment: I meant a typo in the question. You think his real application is sending to `test@gmail.com`?

Comment: sorry! Actually missed this inverted comma only in the question. Now I have modified it

Comment: http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/162004-mail-smtp-server-response-501-syntax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$subject = 'testing';
$email = 'test@gmail.com';
$message = 'test message';          
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: The test site" . "\r\n";


$to=$toEmail;
$subject=$sub;
$from="info@mypropick.com"; 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "From: <".$from.">\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n";
$message='<div style=" width:700px; margin:0 auto; border:1px solid #e2e2e2; padding:20px;">
<h3>MYPROPICK Services:</h3>'.$msg.'</div>';
$message .= "<br/>Regards <br />MYPROPICK.COM";


if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers )) {
  $data['msg']="Message send successfully";
} 
else {
  $data['msg']="Please try again, Message could not be sent!";
}
```

Comment: 1 question: Can we place our own name in the place of sender? In this case instead of From:<"info@mypropick.com"> , can we change to like From:<"info pro pick company"> which is appeared at the sender column of email inbox

Answer (score 0):

a quotes " ' " missed in 3rd line

```
$message = 'test message' ;   
                        ^
```

try :

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: valid@email.com" . "\r\n";
```

`'From'` must be a valid email address

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a closing apostrophe in the code

```
$message = 'test message;
```

should be

```
$message = 'test message';
```

Answer (score 0):

#### SMTP Error 501 : Syntax error in parameters or arguments (e.g. invalid email address)

> The command was correct and recognized, but the parameters (the arguments, e.g. email address) were not valid. For example you try to use invalid email address as `sender\@domain.com` and as `"\"` is not allowed in email addresses.

http://info.webtoolhub.com/kb-a15-smtp-status-codes-smtp-error-codes-smtp-reply-codes.aspx